# Are all complex analytic functions holomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

So we learnt that in $\mathbb{C}$, all holomorphic functions are analytic, and hence infinitely differentiable. (This wasn't proved yet.)

It was also stated that in $\mathbb{R}$, the infinite differentiability doesn't imply that the function is analytic. This function was given as an example:

[image]

My doubts is if a function is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$, is it also
holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$? If not, is there an example for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

- $f:\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ is holomorphic (on all of $\Bbb{C}$) if and only if $f$ is analytic (on all of $\Bbb{C}$).
- For $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$, we have analytic $\implies$ infinitely differentiable, but the converse is false (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Since once it is given as a power series, you can differentiate it term by term.

That the converse is also true is one of the biggest theorems in the subject.  Thus the two notions are equivalent.

Comment: Convergence is not sufficient. It has to be locally uniform convergence. Which we fortunately have for power series.

Comment: Oh. I stand corrected.  @Vercassivelaunos